# How to safely take all elements from a map?

Tags: c++

Basicly, I want do the following.

The `take` extracts all elements from the `Map`, and returns them in a new `Map`. The original `Map` is cleared.

It is very similar to the `take` function in Rust, however, I wonder it is OK to do so in C++?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using Map = std::map<int, std::string>;

Map take(Map & m) {
    // Does this conform to the standard?
    return std::move(m);
}

int main() {
    Map m;
    m.insert({1, "a"});
    printf("%d\n", m.size());
    Map m2 = take(m);
    printf("%d\n", m.size()); // expected to be 0.
    printf("%d\n", m2.size()); // expected to be 1, with (1, "a").
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you including `iostream` and then use `printf`? You also use `printf` wrong so the program has undefined behavior. If you had used `std::cout` instead, you'd be safe.

Comment: why not just `Map m2 = std::move(m);`? Also, moved-from objects generally have some unspecified valid state; m can't be assumed to be empty after moving from it (e.g. some stupid compilers might not be able to move and might make a copy instead).

Comment: @user253751 *"might make a copy instead"* Pretty sure the standard doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
Map take(Map& m) {
    Map new_m;
    swap(new_m, m);
    return new_m;
}
```

I.e. swap the map with a newly created empty map, then return.

Not sure about your code. IIRC a moved object is left in an indeterminate state where the only legal operations are destruction or being overwritten by assignment. So calling `size()` on an object that has been moved is not valid.

Comment: A moved object is left in a valid state, but it's not guaranteed to be any particular one (hence indeterminate or undetermined). It has a size, and it has elements (or no elements) in it. Most likely zero, but you can't assume.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can move construct like that but it will leave `m` in a valid but indeterminate state. You must call `clear()` after it's been "moved from" in order to be able to use it reliably. To invoke the fewest possible constructors, you can make sure it's cleared *after* moving from it:

```cpp
Map take(Map& m) {
    struct clear {
        Map& m;
        ~clear() { m.clear(); } // call m.clear() when it goes out of scope
    } clearer{m};

    return std::move(m);
}
```

This ensures only one move construction + a call to `clear()`.

This setup is similar to using [`std::experimental::scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit) to execute a function at scope exit.

Answer (score 2):

You unnecessarily wrap `std::move`, just do `Map m2 = std::move(m);` directly in `main()`.

As others have noted, it's theoretically possible for `m` to not be empty after this, so you can follow up with `m.clear();`.